# Select single slider element through jQuery instead of all

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a slider and each slide is a `<div>`. For each slide, I would like to toggle a class on it whenever it is clicked. But the problem is that when I click on a slide it is adding class on all slides instead of one that is clicked. How it can be fixed?

Below is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="selling-box-slider">
    <div class="selling-box-slide"></div>

    <div class="selling-box-slide"></div>

    <div class="selling-box-slide"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.selling-box-slide {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 403px;
}

.selling-box-clicked {
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(".selling-box-slide").click(function() {
    jQuery('.selling-box-slide').toggleClass('selling-box-clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this` value inside click handler. `this` value inside an event handler refers to the target element which generated the event:

```
jQuery(".selling-box-slide").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('selling-box-clicked');
});
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked perfectly. Thanks! I will accept this as an answer when it allows me to in about 10 min. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the target of the event to select the proper div as in below.

```js
jQuery(".selling-box-slide").click(function(event) {
        $(event.target).toggleClass('selling-box-clicked');
    });
```

```css
.selling-box-slide {
        background-color: #000;
        height: 403px;
        color: white;
    }

    .selling-box-clicked {
        background-color: #fff !important;
      color:black;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selling-box-slider">
          <div class="selling-box-slide">box 1</div>

          <div class="selling-box-slide">box 2</div>

          <div class="selling-box-slide">box 3</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks for you answer! im sure this will work but muhammad answered just a little before you :D i gave you an upvote though